# When re-initializing a component, my eventlistener stops working

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, event-listener

I have this program with different screens (represented by JPanels). Every time a screen opens I rebuild that panel, and place it on the `JFrame`.

Now, when I build the panel for the first time (always the same function) and press a button, the code attached to it will run. When I rebuild the screen the `eventSource` will never be equal to the actual `eventSource`.

See code:

```
public class NewUserScreen extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    //SButton inherits from Component
    SButton sb;

    ...

    public void SetFields(){
        removeAll();
        revalidate();
        repaint();

        ...     

        sb = new SButton(new Point(282, 295), "Save");
        sb.addMouseListener(this);
        add(sb);

        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getSource().equals(sb)){
            DBManager.addUser(...);
        }else{
            //So after the 2nd build, it will always run this code :(
            ScreenManager.OpenAdminS();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: no idea depends of how is `JPanel` placed to `JFrame`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, just about one `JButton` (invoke add `JPanel` to `JFrame`)  and `JPanel` with one `JComponent` that caused a.m. issue

Comment: I actually forgot the `remove();` etc functions in my actual code. Excuse me, I seem to suffer from braindamage!

Comment: not accepted :-), you forgot to post an SSCCE, everything including my answer here are short to the dark, be sure that issue is somewhere in rest of your code that isn't posted here...

Answer (score 2):

1. > have this program with different screens (represented by JPanels).
   >   Every time a screen opens I rebuild that panel, and place it on the
   >   JFrame.

   - use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of remove and add a new view to [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
2. > Now, when I build the panel for the first time (always the same
   >   function) and press a button, the code attached to it will run. When I
   >   rebuild the screen the eventSource will never be equal to the actual
   >   eventSource.

   - have to call `(re)validate()` and `repaint()` for parent (`JFrame` in your case), one time, as last code lines (after all changes to container are done)